# Merge partially similar arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have values in arrays, which are partially containing the same values, but each array contains some random subset of the values only, for example:

```
$array1 = array("value2", "value3", "value5", "value6");
$array2 = array("value1", "value2", "value3", "value4", "value5");
$array3 = array("value1", "value3", "value4", "value5", "value6" , "value7");
```

I need to merge this kind of arrays (but of course, it can be even more than 3) on the following way:

1. There should be an output array containing **all the values** occuring in the input arrays, **with keeping the original order**. (There is no other logical relationship (like alphabetical order or such) between the values, their position is defined by their distribution in the input arrays. But at least in the background, each of the values has an absolute position, so it's not possible to get ...value1, value2... in one input array, and ...value2, value1... in another input array. It's also important that values are always unique within the arrays, they can't occur repeatedly.) With the given input, the output should be:

   $output: Array
   (
       [0] => "value1"
       [1] => "value2"
       [2] => "value3"
       [3] => "value4"
       [4] => "value5"
       [5] => "value6"
       [6] => "value7"
   )
2. I need to show, **how it's been found and merged**, like a full outer join, but with keeping the order. The output should look like this:

   [image]

I was thinking about using array_merge, or combine it with array_diff but I'm not really sure how to use them together. My idea was to start from the shortest input array, and build up the merged set by fetching the longer ones.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can merge as many arrays as you need with this class

```
<?php

  class mergeArrays {
      private $_arrays ;// keeps an array of arrays that we're going to merge 
      private $arrays_length ;// keeps the length of each array

      function __construct() {
          $this->_arrays = [] ;
          $this->arrays_length = [] ;
      }

      function add_array($arr) {
          sort($arr);
          $this->_arrays[] = $arr ;
          $this->arrays_length[] = count($arr);
      }

      protected function _comp($val1 , $val2) {
          return strcmp($val1,$val2);
      }

      function merge() {
          $res = [];
          $indexes = array_fill(0, count($this->_arrays), 0);
          $exit = false;
          while(!$exit) {
              $min_val = '';
              $min_index = -1;
              for($i =0 ; $i < count($this->_arrays); $i++) { 
                if($indexes[$i] != -1 && $indexes[$i] >= $this->arrays_length[$i]) {
                    $indexes[$i] = -1 ; // it means we check all members of `$i`th array
                }
                if($indexes[$i] != -1 ) {
                    if($min_index === -1 ){
                        $min_index = $i;
                        $min_val = $this->_arrays[$i][$indexes[$i]]; 
                    } else {
                        $cmp_res = $this->_comp( $this->_arrays[$i][$indexes[$i]] ,$min_val );
                        if($cmp_res == -1 ){
                            $min_index = $i;
                            $min_val = $this->_arrays[$i][$indexes[$i]]; 
                        } else if($cmp_res === 0 ) {
                            $indexes[$i]++;
                        }
                    }
                  }
              }

              if($min_index > -1 ) {
                  if(count($res) ===0 || $res[count($res)-1] != $min_val ){
                      $res[] = $min_val;
                  }
                  $indexes[$min_index]++;
              } else {
                  $exit = true ;
              }
          }
          return $res;
      }
  }

  $array1 = array("value2", "value3", "value5", "value6");
  $array2 = array("value1", "value2", "value3", "value4", "value5");
  $array3 = array("value1", "value3", "value4", "value5", "value6" , "value7");

  $obj = new mergeArrays();
  $obj->add_array($array1);
  $obj->add_array($array2);
  $obj->add_array($array3);

  var_dump($obj->merge());
```

Comment: Are you sure? If I run this, i get the following result:

array(11) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "value2"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "value3"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "value5"
  [3]=>
  string(6) "value6"
  [4]=>
  string(6) "value1"
  [5]=>
  string(6) "value2"
  [6]=>
  string(6) "value3"
  [7]=>
  string(6) "value4"
  [8]=>
  string(6) "value5"
  [9]=>
  string(6) "value6"
  [10]=>
  string(6) "value7"
}

Comment: I made a mistake on line 39 and I fixed it. I also add an extra condition on line 50 just in case of that an input array has a duplicated element

Comment: Great, now it's working fine, but in the output, values are in ascending order, not in the order how they originally followed each other in the input. So for example, if I mirror the input arrays, the output still contains value1...7, and not the other way around. I'll have a look on your code's details btw, I really want to understand how you implemented.

Comment: a simpler way is that you add each item of input arrays in the result array ,but before adding item you should check that selected item doesn't exist in result array